# What's the difference between estimation and approximation error?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-learning-theory, bias-variance-tradeoff, approximation-error

I'm unable to find online, or understand from context - the difference between **estimation** error and **approximation** error in the context of machine learning (and, specifically, reinforcement learning).

Could someone please explain with the help of examples and/or references?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Section **5.2 Error Decomposition**](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf#page=64) of the book *Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms* (2014) gives a description of the **approximation error** and **estimation error** in the context of **empirical risk minimization (ERM)** and, in particular, in the context of the **bias-complexity tradeoff** (which is strictly related to the **bias-variance tradeoff**).

### Error/risk decomposition

The expected risk (error) of a hypothesis $h_S \in \mathcal{H}$ selected based on the training dataset $S$ from a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ can be decomposed into the **approximation error**, $\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}$, and the **estimation error**, $\epsilon_{\mathrm{est}}$, as follows

\begin{align}
L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)
&=
\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}+\epsilon_{\mathrm{est}} \\
&=
\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}+ \left( L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)-\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}} \right) \\
&=
\left( \min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h)\right) + \left( L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)-\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}} \right) \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

#### Approximation error

The **approximation error** (AE), aka inductive bias, defined as

$$\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}} = \min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h) $$

is the error due to the specific *choice of hypothesis class* (or set) $\mathcal{H}$. So, $\min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h)$ is minimal risk/error that can be achieved with a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$. In other words, if you limit yourself to $\mathcal{H}$ and you select the "best" hypothesis in $\mathcal{H}$, then $\min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h)$ is the expected risk of that hypothesis.

Here are some properties.

- The larger $\mathcal{H}$ is, the smaller this error is (because it's more likely that a larger hypothesis class contains the actual hypothesis we are looking for). So, if $\mathcal{H}$ does not contain the actual hypothesis we are searching for, then this error could not be zero.
- This error does **not** depend on the training data. You can see in the formula above that there's no $S$ (the training dataset), but only on $D$ (the distribution over the space of inputs and labels from which $S$ was assumed to have been sampled)

#### Estimation error

The **estimation error** (EE) is the *difference* between the *approximation error* $\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}$ and the *error achieved by the ERM predictor* $L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\mathrm{est}}
&=L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)-\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}} \\
&= L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right) - \min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h) 
\end{align}

Here are some properties.

- The estimation error depends on the training dataset $S$. You can see $S$ in the formula above.
- $\epsilon_{\mathrm{est}}$ also depends on the choice of the hypothesis class (given that it is defined as a function of $\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}$).

### Bias-complexity tradeoff

If we increase the size and complexity of the hypothesis class, the **approximation error** *decreases*, but the **estimation error** may *increase* (i.e. we may have *over-fitting*). On the other hand, if we decrease the size and complexity of the hypothesis class, the **estimation error** may decrease, but the *bias* may increase (i.e. we may have *under-fitting*). So, we have a bias-complexity trade-off (where the bias refers to the approximation error or inductive bias) and the complexity refers to the complexity of the hypothesis class.

### Error excess

In [section 4.1](https://mitpress.ublish.com/ereader/7093/?preview=#page/61) of [this book](https://mitpress.ublish.com/ereader/7093/?preview=#page/Cover) also describes a similar (but equivalent) error decomposition, which is called **error excess** because it's a difference between the expected risk and the **Bayes error** (which is sometimes called **inherent error** or **irreducible error**), which they denote by $R^{*}$, while the other book above, which also points out that there's this equivalent **error excess** decomposition, denote it by $\epsilon_{\mathrm{Bayes}}$. So, here's the **error excess**

$$R(h)-R^{*}=\underbrace{\left(\inf _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h)-R^{*}\right)}_{\text {approximation excess}} + \underbrace{\left(R(h)-\inf _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h)\right)}_{\text {estimation error}}$$

So, if you take $R^{*} = \epsilon_{\mathrm{Bayes}}$ from both sides of the equation, you end up with

$$R(h)=\underbrace{\left(\inf _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h) \right)}_{\epsilon_{\mathrm{app}}} + \underbrace{\left(R(h)-\inf _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h)\right)}_{\epsilon_{\mathrm{est}}} \label{2}\tag{2}$$

which is equivalent to equation \ref{1}, where

- $L_{\mathcal{D}}\left(h_{S}\right)    \equiv R(h)$
- $\min _{h \in \mathcal{H}} L_{\mathcal{D}}(h)     \equiv \inf _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h)$

### Illustration

A nice picture that illustrates the relationship between these terms can be found in figure 4.1 of [this book](https://mitpress.ublish.com/ereader/7093/?preview=#page/Cover) (p. 62).

[image]

Here, the red points are specific hypotheses. In this illustration, we can see that the best hypothesis (the Bayes hypothesis) lies outside our chosen hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$. The distance between the risk of $h \in \mathcal{H}$ and the risk of $h^* = \operatorname{arg inf} _{h \in \mathcal{H}} R(h)$ is the **estimation error**, while the distance between $h^*$ and the Bayes hypothesis (i.e. the hypothesis that achieves the Bayes error) is the **approximation excess** in equation \ref{2}.

Comment: Could you please elaborate if the training error on my dataset can ever be zero ? Looking at equation above seems no. However I always thought these equations explain why the difference between train and test error can never be zero.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon I will try to answer your question later. In the first book, they use $L$ to refer to the training error, while, in the second, they refer to it as the expected risk of the hypothesis. I think that this use of different terminology may cause confusion because here the training error is not defined. The second book actually calls what I called the "approximation excess" the "approximation error", but I was trying to connect the definitions of the two books in this answer. There's also a clear distinction between expected risk and empirical risk.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best explained by pictures. Please note that $h_{S}$ is the output of the ERM learner (under the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$) is denoted by $ERM_{\mathcal{H}}$, $f$ is the target hypothesis or the true labeling function. Also:

1. By definition, the approximation error $=\epsilon_{app} := \underset{h\in \mathcal{H}}{min}\ L_{\mathcal{D}}(h)$ is always less than or equal to the estimation error (or the generalization risk/error) $=\epsilon_{est}=\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{D}}(h_{\mathcal{S}})$.
2. The estimation error $\epsilon_{est}=L_{\mathcal{D}}(h_{S})$ is **NOT** the training error (or empirical risk/error) $L_{S}(h_{S})$, rather the estimation error results because of the training error.

A small hypothesis class (or space) $\mathcal{H}$ not containing the target hypothesis $f$, the hypothesis $h_{S} \in \mathcal{H}$ found by the $ERM_{\mathcal{H}}$ learner via training, by some chance - say - small training set size, is not $h^{\star}$. Increasing the training set size may often help (i.e. make $h_{S}$ move closer or even equal to $h^{\star}$):

[image: Small hypothesis class]

Another relatively small but slightly better hypothesis space $\mathcal{H}^{'}$: The approximation error (generalization error comes from the best hypothesis) is smaller than that one, i.e. $h^{\star}$ closely approximates the target function:

[image: Better hypothesis class]

A good hypothesis space $\mathcal{H^{''}}$, of course the best hypothesis class is $\mathcal{H^{'''}}=\{f\}$ but most of the time we don't know what the (class of the) target hypothesis function $f$ is (if we know the function $f$ then learning is redundant), and especially under the assumption of agnostic PAC learning, it's often not a labeling function but rather a data generating distribution:

[image: A good hypothesis class]